# Is ZFC+V=L consistently $\omega$-complete?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

Say that an extension of ZFC is *$\omega$-complete* if any two of its $\omega$-models are elementarily equivalent. While "ZFC+V=L is $\omega$-complete" is easily disprovable in theories only slightly stronger than ZFC, I don't immediately see how to do it in ZFC alone. In particular, my question is:

> Is the theory ZFC + V=L + $\omega$-Con(ZFC+V=L) + "ZFC+V=L is $\omega$-complete" consistent?

("$\omega$-Con(ZFC+V=L)" - the statement "ZFC+V=L has an $\omega$-model" - is included to avoid the trivial answer; of course, I could have written "$\omega$-Con(ZFC)" instead, but I thought this was a bit clearer.)

Note that one difficult here is the current paucity of sentences independent of ZFC+V=L which do not involve a jump in consistency strength and are not arithmetic.

Comment: Don't you still have the trivial answer: go to a model of Con(ZFC) with no $\omega$-model of ZFC.  I think you want to add: "there is an $\omega$-model of ZFC" rather than Con(ZFC).

Comment: @JDH Quite right, fixed!

Comment: For example, any model in which Con(Con(ZFC)) fails, but Con(ZFC) holds, cannot have what it thinks is an $\omega$-model of ZFC.

Comment: To phrase the question differently, what you want is:  a model of ZFC with an $\omega$-model of ZFC, but in which all $\omega$-models of ZFC+V=L have the same theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was negatively answered [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385907/8133) by user Farmer S, using $\omega_1^{CK}$-recursion theory. *(I'm posting this here to move this off the unanswered queue, and have made this CW to avoid reputation gain for someone else's work.)*